# На каком дистрибутиве основан Solus 3 Budgie

Tags: linux, solus

Недавно решил перейти на Linux. Очень понравился дистрибутив Solus 3 Budgie. С Линуксом я уже немного знаком, но сейчас нахожусь на винде. И вот решил узнать, на каком дистрибутиве основан этот дистрибутив, так как мне более знаком Debian. На RPM или на Debian? Кто знаком с этим дистрибутивом, отпишитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: [дистрибутив построен с нуля и не зависит ни от каких других дистрибутивов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solus_project)

Comment: На будущее. Есть шикарный сайт http://distrowatch.com/ . Смотри там.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам знаком `Denian`, то нет необходимости в использовании деривативов, таких как `Ubuntu`, `Kubuntu`, `Lubuntu`, `Kali`, `Mint` и так далее. И я вам настоятельно рекомендую активно изучить именно `Debian`, затем, если понравится, прочитать LFS, и/или поставить `Slackware`.

Касательно вопроса о `Solus 3 Budgie` - то данный дистрибутив не построен на каком-либо дистрибутиве.